# Yielding from a for-comp is not returning the type I want

Tags: scala

Why is the return value a Try[Serializable] for the val maybeString?  I want it to be an Option[String]

```
import scala.util.Try

val a1 = Try("fase".toBoolean)
val b2 = Try("100".toInt)

val maybeString: Option[String] = for {
  a <- a1
  b <- b2
} yield (a,b) match {
  case (true, 50) => "foo"
  case (false, 100) => "bar"
  case _ => None
}

println(s"string is $maybeString")
```

Comment: is this javascript?

Comment: @MarkYisri is that a joke?

Comment: no, I'm just wondering!!

Comment: I must not know the language then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is the return value a Try[Serializable] for the val maybeString?

Because scala compiler cannot determine the type of the element you return in the following expression:

```
(a,b) match {
  case (true, 50) => "foo"
  case (false, 100) => "bar"
  case _ => None
}
```

You return `String` in two cases and `Option` (i.e. `None`) in another one, so it picks up the most common type in hierarchy: `Serializable`.

> I want it to be an Option[String]

```
object Test extends App {

  import scala.util.Try

  val a1 = Try("false".toBoolean)
  val b2 = Try("100".toInt)

  val maybeString: Option[String] = for {
    a <- a1.toOption
    b <- b2.toOption
  } yield (a, b) match {
    case (true, 50) => "foo"
    case (false, 100) => "bar"
  }

  println(s"string is $maybeString")
}
```

Comment: I am confused, there are only 2 possibilities:  String and None.  So it seems obvious to ME that is should be Option[String]  :)    Why can't the compiler figure that out?

Comment: Oh I see, because of the Try's.

Comment: It is statically typed language :) `String` and `Option` are absolutely different. What you want to do is called implicit conversion of `String` type to `Option[String]`. It is not performed automatic by compiler.

Answer (score 1):

You may not need to convert to `Option` until the very last moment:

```
val maybeString: Option[String] = 
  ( for {
    a <- a1
    b <- b2
    s <- Try(
        (a, b) match {
          case (true, 50) => "foo"
          case (false, 100) => "bar"
        }
      )
  } yield (s)).toOption
```

Here I extract `a` and `b` (if they are both successful) and the result of `for` comprehension has a type `Try[String]`. Then I can easily convert it to `Option[String]`.

**UPDATE**

Covered the case when `(a, b)` doesn't match